# Cached re.compile failed to match problem on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Today I tried to cache re.compile to speed up my testing. Something got weird:

I used three cached re.compile:

```
re_cache1=re.compile(regexp_string1)
re_cache2=re.compile(regexp_string2)
re_cache3=re.compile(regexp_string3)
def mytest():
  m = re_cache1.split(data)
  if m:
     for item in m:
       m2 = re_cache2.search(data2)
       if m2:
         m3 = re_cache3.search(data3)
```

The result is not expected, m2 is None. But if I change a little bit, I will get m3's match.

```
       m2 = re.search(regexp_string2, data2)
```

Anybody helps me out? Thanks very much~

Comment: Something else is amiss here, are you sure there isn't some other part of the code that we need to see?

Comment: Sure no other codes, I did that way cause Google suggest to store compiled regular expressions in global variables, then use app caching to re-use the compiled objects between requests. http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html

Comment: Suggestion: check carefully for typos; otherwise publish your real code. Observations: `m` is not a very sensible name for a list. The `if m` test is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind: the re module caches internally anyway.  The difference between:

```
re_cache1 = re.compile(regexp_string1)
...
re_cache1.search(data)
```

and

```
re.search(regexp_string1, data)
```

is one dictionary lookup.  It's usually not worth the extra bookkeeping to cache your own compiled regexes.

Comment: Thanks buddy~ you give me a flash~ but still need more time to figure it all out.

Comment: Depends on how many regexes there are. Last time I looked, when the cache filled up it was emptied ... a bit drastic.

Comment: @John: true, which is why I said "usually".  The cache size is 100 or something like that, and most tight loops of regex searches don't use anywhere near that number.